# AngularJs Code does not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hello everybody and thanks to help me.

Here, the template

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="projectApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Planning Poker !</title>
    <script src="resources/static/js/angular-1.2.21/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/static/js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>Planning Poker</header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Add a Project</li>
            <li>The Project List</li>
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <div ng-controller="GreetingController">
        {{ greeting }}
        </div>
        <!--<form method="post" action="">
            <p><input type="text" placeholder="Name!"></p>
            <p><input type="text" placeholder="Mail!"></p>
            <p><input type="text" placeholder="Password!"></p>
        </form>-->
    </section>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and the controller:

```
var projectApp = angular.module('projectApp', []);

projectApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

And, the directory structure.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWORv.png

The result is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfuHg.png

But I wish "Hola!" and not "{{greeting}}"

Comment: any error from the console?

Comment: are there any console errors?

Comment: Move scripts to the bottom of the page. HTML loads in a linear fashion. And never put scripts above the page, unless you have an specific reason for it.

Comment: No error from the console.
I put scripts under </body>, still does not work

Comment: I'm unsure what issue you're having, works just fine for me in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g8cyfoa9/ all I can think is that the space in front of your doctype is causing issues.

Comment: @MatthieuLobry the scripts need to go before the close of </body> not after.

Comment: Angular has always worked just fine for me in the `<head>` section.

Comment: Oops, sorry I'm dumb.

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/resources/static/js/angular-1.2.21/angular.js"
angular.js
2
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/resources/static/js/controllers

Comment: @Nath, I've used it as a separate file before as well - just couldn't do it in the jsFiddle. Works just fine. and OP, it's saying your file references aren't there. double check your references.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't see the angular.js, try to get the online version, replace your angular.js src with "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is fixed. It was a script problem.

```
<script src="js/angular-1.2.21/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

Indeed, it was directly mapped into "js" directory.